# How do I make this object round like the reference image?

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

I've been learning blender but I cannot get past this problem.

I have this computer mouse shaped object here:

[image]

So here is my reference image:

[image]

What I'd like to do is make it as round as the given image (reference), I have tried methods like bevel and modifiers but those seem to not work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Add a loop to the middle. Also, you may want to check tutorials on YouTube such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SfrxQmR4_dY&t=12s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kind of used the bevel tool and it gave a good result but other parts of the mesh were affected, I'll just ask that in another question.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use subdivision modifier. that way you are able to have more edges and vertices automatically making the mesh smoother instead of blocky

Comment: Unfortunately, the west and east side of the object is thin, which is I do not want.